# How to call JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I was wondering about the different ways of using a JQuery function on a variable
like I know this one

```
$.DoThis(variable);
```

but is there a way to call it at the end like normal Javascript functions

```
variable.$.DoThis();
```

haha I know this sounds stupid but I need to ask somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean

```
$(variable).DoThis();
```

This implies that variable is

- a plain DOM object (or an array of them)
- a jQuery object (or an array of them)
- a string that contains a jQuery selector
- a string that contains HTML/XML markup
- a callback function for the "DOM ready" event (not relevant in this case)

If it something else, all bets are off.

Comment: Also, this may not do the same thing; for example `$.isFunction(someObject)` is not at all the same as `$(someObject).isFunction()` (the latter will presumably always evaluate null as the parameter and return false).

Comment: @JacobM: Yes, of course. But the OP mentioned `$.DoThis(variable)` himself, and seemed to ask "How do I make a jQuery object out of `variable`?". That's why I said "probably" ;)

Comment: Granted, but I think the OP has the expectation that making his variable into a jQuery object, and calling a jQuery function on it, will be the equivalent of calling a jQuery function and passing in his variable.  That expectation, even if the variable is something that's convertible into a jQuery object as you describe, isn't valid.  I'm not criticizing your answer here, I'm pointing out a flaw in (what I think is) the expectation of the OP.